# Problema con #include en C - cannot open source file "unistd.h"

Tags: c, vscode

Estaba probando un código de C sobre una mini-shell para Linux, fue probado en vscode pero antes de ejecutar el código me salía lo siguiente:

[image: error]

**He de aclarar que al parecer esta es la única línea que me marca error**

Y al compilar me muestra lo siguiente:

[image: compiler]

El código es este:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h> //línea del error
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>


#define READ 0
#define WRITE 1

//Funcion utilizada para dividir las cadenas de caracteres dependiendo del delimitador.
void  split(char string[], char *stringdiv[], const char delimiter[] ){
 char *token = strtok(string, delimiter);
 int n = 0;
 while(token != NULL)
 {
  stringdiv[n] = token;
  n++;
  token = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
  stringdiv[n] = NULL;
 }
}
//Funcion que se encarga de redireccionar
void redirectfunction(char *comand[] , char *out[]){
 int file = open(out[0], O_CREAT | O_WRONLY |O_APPEND); //Se abre el archivo donde se guardara la salida del comando a ejecutar
 dup2(file, STDOUT_FILENO); //Permite que se guarde la salida en el archivo file, en lugar de mostrarse por pantalla
 close(file);
 execvp(comand[0], comand);
}

//Funcion que se encarga de pipe funcion
void pipefunction(char *comand[], char *args[]){
 pid_t pid;
 int fd[2];
 if (pipe(fd) == -1) {
  perror("Creating pipe");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }
 pid = fork();
 if (pid == 0){
 //Esta seccion de codigo es ejecutada por el hijo
   close(fd[WRITE]); //Se cierra el descriptor de escritura del pipe
   dup2(fd[READ], STDIN_FILENO);//Permite leer la salida que retorna el padre
   execvp(args[0], args);
   printf("Esto no se deberia imprimir\n");
 }
 else if (pid == -1){
  perror("fork() failed");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }
 else{
 //Esta seccion es ejecutada por el padre
  close(fd[READ]);
  dup2(fd[WRITE], STDOUT_FILENO);
  execvp(comand[0], comand);
 }
}


int main(void) {
  printf("**********MiniShell**********\n");
  printf(">>>  ");
  char  entrada[100];//Se crea un array de cadenas de caracteres para almacenar la entrada
  scanf("%[^\n]", entrada);//Se pide la entrada al usuario, por teclado
  /*Se busca en la cadena de entrada ya sea el simbolo de pipe o el de redireccionamiento para manejar cada caso por separado.
  Este if se ejecuta si en la cadena se encuentra el simbolo de pipe*/
  if( strstr(entrada, "|") != NULL ){
   char *pipe[3];
   split(entrada, pipe, "|");//Se separa la entrada en las dos subcadenas delimitadas por el simbolo|
                             //Cada una de ellas contiene un comando y los argumentos
   char *firstComand[4];  
   char *secondComand[4];
   split(pipe[0], firstComand, " ");//Se separa la cadena por palabras
   split(pipe[1], secondComand, " ");
   pipefunction(firstComand, secondComand);
  }
  else if( strstr(entrada, ">") != NULL){//Se ejecuta si se encuentra el simbolo de direccionamiento
   char *redirect[3];
   split(entrada, redirect, ">");/*Se separa la entrada en dos subcadenas, una de ellas contiene un comando
                                   junto con sus argumentos, la otra contiene el nombre del archivo  donde
                                   se va a redireccionar la salida*/
   char *comand[4];
   char *out[2];
   out[0] = redirect[1];
   out[1] = NULL;
   split(redirect[0], comand, " ");
   redirectfunction(comand, out);
  }else{//Se ejecuta para cualquier comando distinto a casos anteriores
    char *args[7];
    split(entrada, args, " ");
    execvp(args[0], args);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**- Opciones que fui probando**

Ya he investigado para ver de qué se trata e intenté lo siguiente:

1.- supuse que sería algún problema respecto al compilador así que decidí instalar el gcc, sin embargo este no creo que se trate del problema debido a que ya he compilado código antes desde el vscode y usando el Dev-c++, de todas formas, probé el comando "gcc --version" en mi windows y al parecer no me lo reconoce, es como si realmente no lo hubiese instalado. ¿Tendrá algo que ver con eso?

2.- Probé las "Quick Fix..." que me ofrece visual studio code como deshabilitar el subrayado, pero esto no sé si haya solucionado algo debido a que el compilador me marca eso de todas formas...

¿De qué se puede tratar esto? ¿Hay multiples razones?

Comment: Desconozco la compilación que realiza `vscode`, pero he compilado el código directamente con `gcc` y no he tenido problema ninguno.

Comment: `unistd.h` es de linux, tu estas usando Windows. Hasta donde tengo entendido, la forma mas fácil seria usando `msys`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus aportes señores, iré a probar sus respuestas para ver qué tal va.